# Не работает функция the_content(); в single.php

Tags: функции, wordpress

Доброго времени суток, подскажите почему не работает <?php the_content(); ?> в single.php, просто написано, должна работать без цикла the_loop в данном файле, но не работает. Зато работает <?php the_title(); ?>, она без проблем выводит название поста. 
Вот код single.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content-wrap">
            <!--
                --><div class="sidebar" > <?php wp_nav_menu('menu=main_menu'); ?></div><!--

                --><div class="main">
                    <div class="box">

                    <h3>
<a href="" class="post_url"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
     </h3>

       <?php the_content(); ?>

            </div>
                </div><!--

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: вот только кода я тут не вижу, только разметку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо сначала достать контент, как в обычном loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 12):

Добавь `the_post();` в начало

```
<?php
    the_post();
    the_content(); 
?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно использовать функцию `the_post();`

`the_post(`) - Устанавливает индексы поста в Цикле WP. Получает следующий пост, переопределяет глобальную переменную `$post` и устанавливает свойство `in the loop` в `true`.

На отдельных страницах типа `is_single()` не обязательно использовать цикл:

```
if( have_posts() ){ while ( have_posts() ){ the_post(); ...
```

На таких страницах переменная `$post` отвечает за один пост, поэтому часть цикла можно отбросить:

```php
<?php the_post(); ?>

<h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```